# Scrapy Installation on PyCharm Failing Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip, scrapy

I'm pretty new to PyCharm and Scrapy.

I am trying to install Scrapy via the project interpreter but I end with this error.

The error details are

```
Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command C:\Users\Lopino\PycharmProjects\testing-scrapy\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\Lopino\PycharmProjects\testing-scrapy\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix C:\Users\Lopino\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-s7o8n2x7\overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools>=40.6.0 wheel "cffi>=1.8,!=1.11.3; platform_python_implementation != 'PyPy'":
  Collecting setuptools>=40.6.0
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3d/72/1c1498c1e908e0562b1e1cd30012580baa7d33b5b0ffdbeb5fde2462cc71/setuptools-45.2.0-py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/23/848298cccf8e40f5bbb59009b32848a4c38f4e7f3364297ab3c3e2e2cd14/wheel-0.34.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/54/3324b0c46340c31b909fcec598696aaec7ddc8c18a63f2db352562d3354c/cffi-1.14.0.tar.gz
      Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Lopino\PycharmProjects\testing-scrapy\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\msvc.py", line 489, in _find_latest_available_vc_ver
      IndexError: list index out of range

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Lopino\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9v8j1938\cffi\setup.py", line 127, in <module>
          if sys.platform == 'win32' and uses_msvc():
        File "C:\Users\Lopino\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9v8j1938\cffi\setup.py", line 105, in uses_msvc
          return config.try_compile('#ifndef _MSC_VER\n#error "not MSVC"\n#endif')
        File "C:\Users\Lopino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 225, in try_compile
          self._compile(body, headers, include_dirs, lang)
        File "C:\Users\Lopino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 132, in _compile
          self.compiler.compile([src], include_dirs=include_dirs)
        File "C:\Users\Lopino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 360, in compile
          self.initialize()
        File "C:\Users\Lopino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 253, in initialize
          vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
        File "C:\Users\Lopino\PycharmProjects\testing-scrapy\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\msvc.py", line 185, in msvc14_get_vc_env
        File "C:\Users\Lopino\PycharmProjects\testing-scrapy\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\msvc.py", line 843, in __init__
        File "C:\Users\Lopino\PycharmProjects\testing-scrapy\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\msvc.py", line 485, in __init__
        File "C:\Users\Lopino\PycharmProjects\testing-scrapy\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\msvc.py", line 492, in _find_latest_available_vc_ver
      distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

      ----------------------------------------
  Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Lopino\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9v8j1938\cffi\

  ----------------------------------------

Command "C:\Users\Lopino\PycharmProjects\testing-scrapy\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\Lopino\PycharmProjects\testing-scrapy\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix C:\Users\Lopino\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-s7o8n2x7\overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools>=40.6.0 wheel "cffi>=1.8,!=1.11.3; platform_python_implementation != 'PyPy'"" failed with error code 1 in None
```

I have anaconda installed and my project environment variable path looks like this

[image: environment path]

Later I tried installing using pip install Scrapy but I end up with the same error.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\lopino\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Lopino\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9cxt7mmh\\Twisted\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Lopino\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9cxt7mmh\\Twisted\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Lopino\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-w4qeyi_1\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\lopino\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\Twisted' Check the logs for full command output.
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: see in first error message: _Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/_ Did you download and install it? Simply it has code in C/C++ and it needs compiler and other elements to compile it.

Comment: I already install the tool found here https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/ but still no luck

Comment: Try installing using wheel [link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)